# finding an element in an array by comparing it with another array

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix

```
a = [ 1 'cancer'
      2 'cancer'
      3 'cancer'
      4 'noncancer'
      5 'noncancer' ]
```

I have another matrix with values

```
b = [ 4
      5
      2 ]
```

Now I have to compare the b matrix values with values of a and the output should be

```
output = [ 4  'noncancer'
           5  'noncancer'
           2  'cancer']
```

How can I do this in matlab ?

Comment: `a` is a cell array and **not** a matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
a = { 1 'cancer'
      2 'cancer'
      3 'cancer'
      4 'noncancer'
      5 'noncancer' };

  b = [ 4
      5
      2 ];

 a(ismember([a{:,1}], b),:)
```

This results in

```
ans = 

    [2]    'cancer'   
    [4]    'noncancer'
    [5]    'noncancer'
```

To display the results in the order specified by `b` use (as requested in a follow-up question: [In the same order, finding an element in an array by comparing it with another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250510/in-the-same-order-finding-an-element-in-an-array-by-comparing-it-with-another-a))

```
[logicIDX, numIDX]  = ismember(b, [a{:,1}]);
a(numIDX, :)
```

This results in:

```
ans = 

   [4]    'noncancer'
   [5]    'noncancer'
   [2]    'cancer'
```