# In the same order, finding an element in an array by comparing it with another array

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix

```
a = [ 1 'cancer'
      2 'cancer'
      3 'cancer'
      4 'noncancer'
      5 'noncancer' ]
```

I have another matrix with values

```
b = [ 4
      5
      2 ]
```

Now I have to compare the b matrix values with values of a and the output should be

```
output = [ 4  'noncancer'
           5  'noncancer'
           2  'cancer']
```

if I use

```
a(ismember([a{:,1}], b),:)
```

I get
ans =

```
[2]    'cancer'   
[4]    'noncancer'
[5]    'noncancer'
```

How to get the result in the same order ? as shown below

```
output = [ 4  'noncancer'
           5  'noncancer'
           2  'cancer']
```

Comment: You've asked an almost exact question here: [finding an element in an array by comparing it with another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220920/finding-an-element-in-an-array-by-comparing-it-with-another-array). Instead of asking the same question with a slightly different flavor, I suggest that you post a comment to the answerer for clarification.

Comment: @Mrk: I updated my answer to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220920/finding-an-element-in-an-array-by-comparing-it-with-another-array

Comment: @H.Muster Thank you very much. I didn't know the fact that, I can ask for more clarification in the answer to the same question.

Comment: @EitanT Thank you. Here after I would ask for clarification in the result instead of asking a new question

Comment: @Mrk: I guess that whether you ask for clarification or open a new question depends on how big or difficult a follow-up question is. There might be different opinions on that but no strict rules.